# Date request with switch case function delivers no result

Tags: php, date, switch-statement

I've created a PHP code that checks the day of a month. Depending on the daynumber a different colorcode should be generated in my CSS.

Today is the 8th January, so in this case the hex `#FFD500` should be the value of background-color. Even though echoing the current day delivers "08", the background-color value is empty.

Why doesn't get the hex for 08 displayed in the background-color?

```
<?php 

    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

    $i = date(d);

    switch ($i) {

        case 05: $TopColor = '#A60000'; break;
        case 09: $TopColor = '#009EFF'; break;
        case 13: $TopColor = '#8200A6'; break;
        case 16: $TopColor = '#FFD500'; break;
        case 17: $TopColor = '#003CA9'; break;
        case 25: $TopColor = '#087E00'; break;
        case 30: $TopColor = '#C300AB'; break;
        case 31: $TopColor = '#00B8B8'; break;
        case 11: $TopColor = '#FFE211'; break;
        case 10: $TopColor = orange; break;
        case 08: $TopColor = '#FFD500'; break; 
    }

?>

.site-header {
    background-color: <?php echo $TopColor; ?>;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to put quotes around the format of `date()` like:

```
$i = date("d");
```

Second you have also to put quotes around the numbers, because otherwise they gets interpreted as octal numbers! So do something like this:

```
case "08":
```

Also put quotes around this:

```
case "10": $TopColor = "orange"; break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing string with Integer. date() function returns String.
Check [link](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.date-sun-info.php)

You can use `$i=intval(date('d'))` //convert to integer